# Error "Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file '" x y 0 2 0.5 -1 1 3 "' inrefer to the pgfplotstable manual for details). \end{frame}"

Tags: pgfplots, errors

In this Code I try to insert the code in page 408 of pgf manual

```
    \begin{frame}{Motivation}
        \begin{center}
    \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.13}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=4.521in,
    height=3.566in,
    at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
    scale only axis,
    ticks=none,
    xmin=-0,
    xmax=10,
    ymin=-0,
    ymax=5,
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    legend style={at={(0.658,0.788)},anchor=south west,legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=white!15!black}
    ]
    \addplot+[domain=1:10,/pgfplots/no markers,samples=200] {4/\x^0.5};
    \addplot+[name path=A,domain=0:1,samples=2] {x};
    \addplot+[name path=B] table {
        x y
        0 2
        0.5 -1
        1 3
    };
    \addplot fill between[of=A and B];
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \captionof{figure}{Caption}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
```

but I got errors as:

```
Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file '" x y 0 2 0.5 -1 1 3 "' inrefer to the pgfplotstable manual for details). \end{frame}
```

Comment: looks like your editor doesn't like the return character.

Comment: Ehhhhhhhhhh. What does this mean?

Comment: it means it doesn't recognize the line breaks and thinks that it is a just a single line. Type it manually on a fresh document instead of copy/pasting to verify

Comment: If retyping does not help, add the option `table/row sep=\\ ` and terminate each data line by `\\ `, like this: `\addplot+[name path=B, table/row sep=\\] table  {x y\\0 2\\0.5 -1\\1 3\\};`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is due to an editor issue.